# PHP/PDO: Insert data into foreign column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

i am very new at all of this... Here is my code (which i originally got from [here](https://www.taniarascia.com/create-a-simple-database-app-connecting-to-mysql-with-php/))

```html
<?php

/**
 * Use an HTML form to create a new entry in the
 * users table.
 *
 */


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    require "../config.php";
    require "../common.php";

    try  {
        $connection = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
        
        $new_user = array(
            "firstname" => $_POST['firstname'],
            "lastname"  => $_POST['lastname'],
            "email"     => $_POST['email'],
            "age"       => $_POST['age'],
            "location"  => $_POST['location']
        );

        $sql = sprintf(
                "INSERT INTO %s (%s) values (%s)",
                "users",
                implode(", ", array_keys($new_user)),
                ":" . implode(", :", array_keys($new_user))
        );
        
        $statement = $connection->prepare($sql);
        $statement->execute($new_user);
    } catch(PDOException $error) {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $error->getMessage();
    }
}
?>

<?php require "templates/header.php"; ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) { ?>
    <blockquote><?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?> successfully added.</blockquote>
<?php } ?>

<h2>Add a user</h2>

<form method="post">
    <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname">
    <label for="email">Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
    <label for="age">Age</label>
    <input type="text" name="age" id="age">
    <label for="location">Location</label>
    <input type="text" name="location" id="location">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<a href="index.php">Back to home</a>

<?php require "templates/footer.php"; ?>
```

This code worked just fine without fk columns. But in PHPAdmin I now made "location" a foreign column. The parent table looks like this:

**Location**

location INT (PK)

location name VARCHAR

I added a few locations to the parent table but still when i execute the code above, this error appears:

**SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'location' cannot be null**

How do I define the foreign key? Do I need a SELECT statement? I tried several things but I just cannot make it work. I'm about to give up so I'm posting on here.

Thank you very much for any answer!

PS: Maybe anybody can recommend any reading/books on this specific topic of PHP/PDO/SQL?

Comment: There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. It's complaining you didn't supply a value for the location field, which implies you forgot to type a value into it in the form.

Comment: Of course you could make it easier for the user by making the location field on the form into a dropdown list of all the possible locations stored in the Location table, so they don't have to know the ID to submit

Comment: BTW I'm assuming you changed the "location" column in your "users" table into an INT column and that you made it a foreign key of the "location" INT column in the Location table (not a foreign key of the "location name" field, I hope)?

Comment: yes i did change it to INT in phhmyadmin... Do I need to change it somewhere in the code as well? Thank you for your comment and for the recommendation about the drop down list.

Comment: No, you needn't do that. PHP doesn't have strict data typing. You just need to debug and find out why it  isn't sending a "location" value to the database